# SSAS: Parent-child hierarchy inside hierarchy (multidimensional cube)

Tags: multidimensional-array, ssas, parent-child, hierarchy, cube

Here's a snippet from my dataset:

```
PrimaryKey          
taskID  TaskParentID    projectID   customerID
1       0               1           1
2       0               1           1
3       0               2           1
4       3               2           1
5       3               2           1
6       5               2           1
7       5               2           1
8       0               3           2
9       0               4           2
10      9               4           2
11      0               5           3
12      11              5           3
13      0               6           3
14      0               6           3
```

I want to build a dimension in SSAS with a hierarchy like this:

[image]

I can build the Task / Sub task parent-child hierarchy - but how do I link it to projects and customers? Is it even possible in one dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the parent-child hierarchy with just the Task columns. Then install BIDS Helper and run [this feature](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/features/Parent-ChildDimensionNaturalizer/). It will create a leveled table and dimension from your parent child hierarchy. Then add the customer and project levels to the top of the natural hierarchy.